# Session data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple program that manages documents' data. A document has a `branch_id` & `subject_id`. 
Some documents have: 
a) Only the `branch_id` & `subject_id` is `null`. 
b) Only the `subject_id` & `branch_id` is `null`. 
c) Both the `branch_id` & `subject_id`.

I need to separate all the files by the above criteria. In my project, I used the following code to do this

```
if ($this->session->userdata('branch_id'))
      $this->db->where('tbl_documents.branch_id', $this->session->userdata('branch_id'));
if ($this->session->userdata('subject_id'))
      $this->db->where('tbl_documents.subject_id', $this->session->userdata('subject_id'));
```

How can I modify above code to fulfill criteria c) mentioned above. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The code that you are using right now seems logically okay and would meet your 3 conditions(a, b and c)! The only thing you need to bother is, what if both the `branch_id` and `subject_id` is null. @DFriend already mentioned this in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Associative array method

```js
if (($this->session->userdata('branch_id')) && ($this->session->userdata('subject_id')))
{
  $where = array(
                'branch_id' => $this->session->userdata('branch_id'), 
                'subject_id' => $this->session->userdata('subject_id')
                );
 }
else if($this->session->userdata('branch_id'))
{
  $where = array('branch_id' => $this->session->userdata('branch_id'));
}
else if($this->session->userdata('subject_id'))
{
  $where = array('subject_id' => $this->session->userdata('subject_id'));
}
else
{
  $where = array('1' => '1'); //You probably don't need this case.
}

$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->get('tbl_documents');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to do anything.

Let's assume you're asking for all fields from `tbl_documents` so the "base-line" query statement is

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_documents
```

That will not change unless one or both of the `if` statements are true.

If the first is true, then the query statement becomes

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_documents WHERE tbl_documents.branch_id = some_branch_id;
```

However, if the first were false and the second true then the statement would be

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_documents WHERE tbl_documents.subject_id = some_subject_id;
```

Should both `if` conditions be true the query statement would be

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_documents WHERE tbl_documents.branch_id = some_branch_id 
                             AND tbl_documents.subject_id = some_subject_id;
```

Doesn't that satisfy the criteria "c"?

The question I have is, what if both conditions are false? Is `SELECT * FROM tbl_documents` (no WHERE conditions) a query you actually want to run?

Comment: DFriend. You are totally wrong. This is not a single user system. Relevant files should be filtered by relevant user on the each session.

Comment: Do you understand that  `some_branch_id` is a place holder for the value of `$this->session->userdata('branch_id')`?

Comment: @CaptainRed, Your code is the hard way to get to the same place.